# Need explanation about my fibonacci program

Tags: c, fibonacci

In my code below, `fibr(n)` and `fibnr(n)` each return an int.  When `n` is small, the returned values are correct, but when `n` is larger, the result overflows, and the result is no longer reliable.  If the return type remains an `int`, what is the range of `n` where the results are accurate?  What about if the return type is `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, or `unsigned long long`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibr (int n ) {    // using recursive method
    if (n==0) return 0 ;
    else if (n==1) return 1;
    else {
        return (fibr(n-1)+2*fibr(n-2));
    }
}

int fibnr (int n ) {
    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    if (n==0) return a;
    else if (n==1) return b;
    else {
        int sum=0 ;
        int i ;
        for (i=2;i<=n;i++) {
            sum=a+(2*b);
            a=b;
            b=sum;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you more clearly explain your problem?

Comment: When I test your fib functions, I get these results: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca9428d07e1b8c11.  (Interestingly, both of these are the wrong results)

Comment: The return statement in your recursive function is: return (fibr(n-1)+2*fibr(n-2));

I believe it should be: return (fibr(n-1)+fibr(n-2));

Comment: @MooingDuck am using a function f(n)=f(n-1)+2f(n-2)

Comment: @StephenB this is the function that i asked to write a program for

Comment: The explanation is "integer overflow". Look it up.

Comment: `sum=a+(2*b);` --> `sum=b+(2*a);`

Comment: As BLUEPIXY notes, `fibnr` is calculating the wrong value, so its result won't be the same as that of `fibr`. Is *that* what your question is about? Please note that nowhere in your post is there an actual *question*. The first step in formulating a good question at SO (and yours is very much not good) is to actually make it one.

Comment: @JimBalter  my question is: if the returned value of f(n) is defined as an (integer,unsigned integer,a long integer,unsigned long integer) from which n,the returned value of f(n) is not reliable

Comment: @mira: Can you find an english speaker to help you clarify?  We can't figure out what it is you're trying to ask us. :(

Comment: @MooingDuck sorry but am new mumber that's why

Comment: @mira: It has nothing to do with if you're a new member or not, and everything to do with not being able to communicate technical details clearly in English.

Comment: @MooingDuck ok i will try my best next time

Comment: @MooingDuck ;  my question is that if the returned value of f(n) is defined as an integer , from which n ,the returned value of f(n) is not reliable,the  same question if it's defined as unsigned integer ,long integer , unsigned long integer .

Comment: @mira: Oh, I get it!  I've edited the question, did I get it right?  If so, we'll start removing the hold and downvotes (though that process takes time)

Comment: @MooingDuck yes u get the question thnx

Comment: @MooingDuck I pointed out what the question is about quite a while ago ... I thought it followed from the listing of the integer types that "reliable" referred to integer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type Name             |   Bytes   |     Ranges of Values
-------------------------------------------------------------------
integer               |     4     | –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
                      |           |
unsigned integer      |     4     | 0 to 4,294,967,295
                      |           |
long integer          |     4     | –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
                      |           |
unsigned long integer |     4     | 0 to 4,294,967,295
                      |           |
long long             |     8     | –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
                      |           |
unsigned long long    |     8     | 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

So you just have to check the "real" fibonacci sequence and see when your output will be over the range depending on which type you decided to pick... With the type "unsigned long long" you are up to the 93th number of the sequence beyond you have to take something else. Maybe a library that can handle large number or you switch to double (up to 1.7e+/-308).

Comment: The number of bytes and range depend on your compiler and architecture, but these results are accurate for VC++ targetting x86 and x64.

Comment: Question has been clarified slightly